# Migrating from Sencha Touch 1.1.x to Sencha Touch 2

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

The [Sench Touch 2 preview post](http://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-touch-2-developer-preview/) mentions that Jamie Avins will talk about migrating from ST1 to ST2 at SenchaCon. Are there are any guides on how to upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No guides on migration that I know of but I have put together a sample app for touch 2.0 based on the ExtJS 4.0 MVC architecture. Maybe you could refer to this one and essentially map the differences.

https://github.com/FrancisShanahan/SenchaTouch2MVCHelloworld

Some of the new features in 2.0 I believe are the Component Queries and automatic getter generation for views, models, stores etc. and of course improved performance.

http://francisshanahan.com/index.php/2011/sencha-touch-2-0-mvc-in-5-minutes-or-less/

Hope it helps,
-fs

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this would help you http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/getting_started . But in my opinion it's too early for solid guides since the ST2 is still so fresh and will probably change soon.

Answer (score 1):

Ripper of a blog post here: http://www.sencha.com/learn/upgrading-to-sencha-touch-2-pr2

Answer (score 1):

Here are what I found so far:

http://www.sencha.com/conference/session/migrating-from-touch-1.x-to-2.0

http://www.sencha.com/learn/upgrading-to-sencha-touch-2-pr2/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

They put a video of Jamie's talk here:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/video/migrating-from-1-to-2

It's long but informative.